# A linearization in optimization problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linearization

The step $\boldsymbol{\beta}^{t+1}$ in solving an optimization problem
is given below.

$$\boldsymbol{\beta}^{t+1}=\mathrm{argmin}_{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\frac{1}{2}\left\Vert \mathbf{u}^{t}-\boldsymbol{\alpha}^{t+1}+\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{A}\boldsymbol{\beta}\right\Vert _{2}^{2}+\frac{1}{\rho}\left\Vert \boldsymbol{\beta}\right\Vert _{1}$$

The source stated that with a linearization in $\boldsymbol{\beta}=\boldsymbol{\beta}^{t+1}$,
the expression can be written as
$$\boldsymbol{\beta}^{t+1}=\mathrm{argmin}_{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\frac{1}{2}\left\Vert \boldsymbol{\beta}-\boldsymbol{\beta}^{t}+\mathbf{A}^{T}\left(\mathbf{A}\boldsymbol{\beta}^{t}-\mathbf{u}^{t}+\boldsymbol{\alpha}^{t+1}-\mathbf{r}\right)/\gamma\right\Vert _{2}^{2}+\frac{1}{\rho\gamma}\left\Vert \boldsymbol{\beta}\right\Vert _{1}$$
where $\gamma=\left\Vert \mathbf{A}\right\Vert _{2}^{2}$. Here, $\left\Vert \mathbf{A}\right\Vert _{2}$ to
denote the largest singular value of $\mathbf{A}$. Can you
help me with how this statement was obtained?

([source](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flare/vignettes/vignette.pdf), Equations (3) and (8).)